# How to summarize fields of multiple feature classes using ModelBuilder or Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

I'm new to ModelBuilder.
I have created a script in python that gives results for each month, using ModelBuilder how can I make a sum between each field of each month of the year to have a single feature class with the totals. Here is a figure explains what I am looking for.
[image]

Comment: Does the tables have geometries? Are they the same? Or do you just want a table output?

Comment: Placing "or ArcPy" in the title makes this two questions. Since you don't actually mention ArcPy in the body, it would be better to remove the title text and tag.

Comment: thank you for your comment BERA, Vince, yes, the tables have their geometries, they are the polygons of the buildings in a district. i have calculated their energy needs for each month, and i want to do the total for the whole year through Modelbuilder or through an Arcpy script. but i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: the fields of the table of the 12 feature class are the same.

Comment: Please make sure that any text you include on pictures to try and explain your question also appears as formatted text within your question body.  That way it's available to searches and easily read on all devices.

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood what you want, you could do this:

1. In each table add a new field and populate it with the year, so each row in the table is the year. I see that as functionality written into your existing script.
2. [Merge](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) all the tables into a single table
3. Run summary [statistics tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) summing the fields but grouping by the year. This will generate your sums in a new table

Comment: thank you Hornbydd for your feedback !
I have tested your proposal, the tables have their geometries sorry I didn't mention it, they are the polygons of the buildings of a district. when I merge them, I get for each building 12 duplicate polygons for the 12 Months. but what I'm looking for is a single polygon of the building with the total of 12 months.

Comment: Does each polygon have a building ID that is the same in each table, so for example the same building is always X. If so simply add another group by field in the summary statistics tool.